# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'home'

Tags: python, django, attributeerror

I've been following this guide on the first steps to setting up a website, but I'm getting an attributeerror when trying to launch the website in development mode. The link to the guide is: https://www.zeolearn.com/magazine/first-steps-to-create-the-website-with-django

I've pasted the git bash output i get when i try to `$ python manage.py migrate` and the url.py file below it.

```
$ python manage.py migrate

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 327, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 62, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super(Command, self)._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 256, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 407, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 400, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\users\says\desktop\WEB\Web_Site\Web_Site\urls.py", line 24, in <module>
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'home'
```

The url.py code is below

```
"""Web_App URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.conf.urls import url, include
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^home$', views.home, name='home'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

I've looked at a number of posts on stackoverflow and other websites but I can't seem to figure out what it is about `url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')` that is causing this error.

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: views.py file has the following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
```

Comment: Considering that the error is because your local module `views` has no attribute `home` you should post the contents of `./views.py` so that folks can help you

Comment: `views.home` this expect you have `def home()` in file `views.py`. Do you have it?

Comment: edited my post to include views.py script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to add

```py
def home(request):

   return render(request, 'Web_App/home.html')
```

in your views.py